# helm-info list of info pages cannot find newly installed packages?

Tags: helm, info

I like reading my documentation using emacs. The nature of documentation is that you often want to read documentation immediately after installing it.

Whilst running emacs I installed the documentation for gnuplot (`sudo apt-get install gnuplot-doc`), and the command `info gnuplot` shows me documentation. However, `helm-info` doesn't list gnuplot.

Now obviously I could restart emacs... but I don't like restarting emacs for obvious reasons. I've tried running  `(setq helm-info--pages-cache nil)` and killing then `*helm Info*` buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of Info files is stored in [`helm-default-info-index-list`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/v2.5.4/helm-info.el#L159), a customizable variable.

Re-evaluating `helm-default-info-index-list` will make newly installed Info files available.

This does seem like an inconvenience. I'll see about [fixing it in a PR](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/pull/1734/files).

**Update**: the PR has been [merged](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/e5d5b8d182cef274fd38ba8104f88f822cb5a84a).